# Override the typehead suggestion ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm stuck trying to override the suggestion of ng-bootstrap. I want to write in the input only the street name, without the street number. For example if the user types "Fake street 123", the suggestions could be "['Fake 12, Fake street 123, Fake street 111',...]" and when He choose one, I want to write in the input only the street name ("fake street").

My example code is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qejkgm?

[here are the suggestions, example evergreen 123](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMHl3.png)

[when its click, I want just the evergreen part, without the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chcxa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the change event like this :

**(change)="IWantOnlyTheStreetNameInTheInput()"**

**Ts:**

```
IWantOnlyTheStreetNameInTheInput() {
  let val = this.myForm.controls['streetName'].value;
  //removing all the numbers or any other algorithms
  this.myForm.patchValue({streetName : val.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') }) 
}
```

**Html**

```
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control"   [ngbTypeahead]="search" (change)="IWantOnlyTheStreetNameInTheInput()" formControlName="streetName"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, it kind of works, but it changes when it loose focus on the input. I will be great if it get fired when the user selects the suggestion.